# Update column B based on Column A for all rows in table

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, subquery

I need to insert hash value into column b based on value of column a, but I need to do this for every row in table.

I always get this error no matter what I tried:

```
ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I have been trying different versions of the following:

```
UPDATE table
SET column b = md5((SELECT column a FROM table))
WHERE column a IS NOT NULL;
```

Any suggestions on how to perform this operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a subquery here. As I understand, you want to store the checksum of `column_a` in `column_b`. As one would expect, Postgres' `md5()` function expects a single, scalar argument of string datatype, so:

```
UPDATE table
SET column_b = md5(column_a)
WHERE column_a IS NOT NULL;
```

Note that it would probably be simpler to use a computed column (available in Postgres 12) to store this derived information.